# Nested DIV - Title attribute not working in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have the following code :

```
<div><div title="My Title">My Text</div></div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a637exbt/)

In IE, the title is showing correctly but nothing appear in Chrome.

Someone know why ?

Comment: Works just fine for me...

Comment: You're right. I just rebooted my PC and it works !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Cameron comment, I found that no title at all was showing so I decided to reboot my PC. This fixed the problem !!